# How do I add a unit of measure to my result?

Tags: python

```
# assign the value 12 to the base
base = 12

# assign the value 16 to the height
height = 16

# assign the results of the operation to the variable area
# the operation multiplies base by height

# assign the area of a triangle formula
area = (1/2) * (base*height)

# print the value of triangle area
print(area)
```

Comment: Please formulate your questions a little more. I don't know the unit. Assuming squared meters and a float what you want is `print("{:.2f} squared meters".format(area))`. Check https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/ for all the types of string formatting.

Comment: Always add the desired output to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:
`print(area, "put unit here")`